# Check if an element and its children have been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know the `.load()` function in jQuery, and how to use the callback function with that... but is there a way to check if an element has been loaded using an `if` statement?

My reasoning... I want to set an interval and check if an element and all it's children have been fully loaded.

```
var load-interval = setInterval(function(){
    if($('#content').hasBeenLoaded){
        //do stuff
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why do you want to check after a certain interval? What event will begin the interval?

Comment: @Coenwulf What does it matter? This event will be triggered as soon as possible

Comment: I ask because that information may lead to a better answer.

Comment: @Adjit what's wrong with the callback method?  It's the only way to get a direct notification.

Comment: @Alnitak just trying to keep it simple. And also the content I am checking is not being dynamically loaded, so when I would run this function, either it won't be able to run because of other elements not existing yet or the page will already be loaded when it comes to execute

Comment: So this content is part of the original page load?

Comment: so if you're not using `.load` at all, why mention it?  It just confuses...

Comment: @Alnitak because then everyone would've said 'why don't you just use load?'

Comment: @Adjit see my answer - the trivial way to check that `#content` is loaded is to put that code directly in the page after that element, because by definition at that point is _is loaded_.  You can also then check for completion of any image assets that it included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $content = $('#content');
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    if(!$content.is(':empty')){
        //do stuff
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Just note that elements that contains only text nodes considered to be non empty by the [spec](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

Comment: won't the element still appear full of its previous contents until the moment immediately after the AJAX content is returned and inserted in its place?

Comment: @Alnitak, I won't lie to you, I have no idea what the questioner wants to accomplish here and why not using the `load` callback as this is the right way of doing it. **I only answered his question:**   _"but is there a way to check if an element has been loaded using an if statement?"_

Comment: @gdoron I was not loading anything via ajax, but I may consider altering my workflow... just trying to keep it as a simple page.

Comment: @Adjit if your intent is for example to check that all of the images within `#content` are loaded, this won't do it, because the `:empty` selector is looking for (any) DOM nodes, not loaded assets.

Answer (score 1):

During initial page load, your DOM elements are progressively created as the file is parsed, but image assets are typically loaded asynchronously as they're referenced.

So, as your page loads, the parser will come across the element `<div id="mycontent">`.

This element will be created immediately, and then its children, and then eventually the closing tag for that div will be found.  At that point you could consider that the DOM itself is "loaded" for that element.

The simplest way to execute something then is to put it in a `<script>` tag immediately after that closing tag.

If you also want to wait for the image assets to load, then this is still the place to put it.  You can look for all `<img>` tags within the previously loaded div, and register `onload` callbacks, e.g.

```
<div id="mycontent">
    lots of DOM, including image tags
</div>
<script>
(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('mycontent'); // guaranteed to exist
    var imgs = div.getElementsByTagName('img');

    // put image load detection code here - exercise for the reader
})();
</script>
```